# Update and save face recognition model

Tags: opencv, model, face-recognition

Face recognition model can be created , saved and reloaded. ( http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contri...)

Can this model be updated with new faces?

Answer (score 1):

The face recognition model can be updated by using [**`FaceRecognizer::update()`**](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/opencv-2.4.10-docs/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html#facerecognizer-update), but only for the **Local Binary Patterns Histograms (LBPH) recognizer**.

> This method updates a (probably trained) FaceRecognizer, but only if the algorithm supports it. **The Local Binary Patterns Histograms (LBPH) recognizer (see `createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`) can be updated. For the Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces method, this is algorithmically not possible and you have to re-estimate the model with `FaceRecognizer::train()`**. In any case, a call to train empties the existing model and learns a new model, while update does not delete any model data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll test LBP recognizer with live faces.